# how do you insert data into a table correctly using INSERT INTO?

Tags: mysql, relational-database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to SQL and relational databases, but am writing the code to add data into tables I have created. I am not sure if the code I have written is correct for inserting into a table. Can anyone tell me if this is correct please.

```
INSERT INTO Job (Job_ID, Job_name) 
            VALUES (‘1’, ‘Teacher’);
```

Comment: You have curly single quotes instead of straight single quotes `’` instead of `'`.

Comment: You can also see the "SO Documentation" !! You will learn a lot of things: how to insert, update, select, etc. Feel free to see the Documentation from SO (top of SO page, under your profile).

Answer (score 0):

You code is right but if you use autoincrement column for job_id  you should use

and  use single  quote s and not  `‘`

```
INSERT INTO Job ( Job_name) 
        VALUES ( 'Teacher');
```

otherwise the code you prodivided

```
INSERT INTO Job (Job_ID, Job_name) 
        VALUES ('1', 'Teacher );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this :

```
insert into table_name set column_first = 'value_first' and column_second = 'value_second'
```

Answer (score 0):

make correction:

```
INSERT INTO Job (Job_ID, Job_name) 
            VALUES ('1', 'Teacher');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert value with this syntax 
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
As per your code you can write 
INSERT INTO Job (Job_ID, Job_name) 
            VALUES ('1', 'Teacher');

Answer (score 0):

This my help:
[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

simple insertion 
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);